# How to create Admin user in a remote Apostrophe server

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am fairly new to Apostrophe and was wondering how I could create an admin user for my server running in a containerized environment. The login page is currently available at https://mywebsite.com/login

When i was running locally, I would open up a new terminal window and type node `./src/app.js apostrophe-users:add admin "admin"` which would then prompt me for a password and then we had an admin.

How can this be done on a remote server freshly deployed with apostrophe? Is there a specific endpoint that needs to be hit to create the first admin user?

Any bit of information on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that command remotely in your container. Docker supports this, see:

https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/11266726